# Free solution to backup folders to external SFTP server with shadow copy

Tags: windows-7, linux, backup, sftp, shadow-copy

I have an account in university on Linux machine with 10TB of free space accessible via SFTP. I would like to backup my Windows 7 x64 laptop to university. Currently I am using rsync+cygwin, but backup is pretty slow (without shadow copy) and I hate console window appearing every day on my screen when I login.

So I am looking for something like Windows Backup but with support for SFTP. Combination of tools will work too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Duplicity is a nice backup tool written in Python, and there are various frontends or reimplementations (e.g. [Duplicati](http://www.duplicati.com/)).

It supports encryption and a lot of different backends (scp/sftp being one of them).

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. This is better then rsync+cygwin, but Shadow Copy is not used.

Comment: Latest stable version of Duplicati was not usable, since it was buggy (backup never succeeded). However, I have downloaded and built from source, and it appear that it works better and also has more features :).

Comment: Not quite an answer to my question, but I found this most helpful. Thank you -- bounty is yours. :)

Answer (score 1):

not the entire solution but [this should be a part of it](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/scripting) you can probably use piping, or backup locally, then use that on SFTP/winscp i suppose.

Comment: According to your solution I will have to create local backup before transferring it to the university via automated script for WinSCP. However, the problem is that I don't have enough space on my laptop to store one.

Answer (score 0):

[SyncBack Pro](http://www.2brightsparks.com/syncback/sbpro.html) will do what you want very neatly.  It isn't free but it is quite cheap.  I use it to back up my remote email server to my Windows box, as well as running all my other backup jobs.

You could probably also rig something using the cheaper SyncBack SE and an SSH tunnel using something like Tunnelier.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, but I am not willing to pay $45 just for slight difference from free open-source solutions. Moreover, suggested by blueeyed, Duplicati is almost perfect solution to me. The only feature is lacks is Shadow Copy, but as far as I know it's going to be implemented in version 1.2